# Irregular Verbs with Compound Predicates

Tags: verbs, past-perfect, past-participles, irregular-verbs

Are both of these sentences acceptable?

1. We **had** manufactured it but **gave** it to someone else.
2. We **had** manufactured it but **given** it to someone else.

Is there a rule that says the past perfect must be used in the dependent clause if it appears in the main clause?

Comment: Unless you have an irregular verb, like *give*, people may assume that the past perfect is used in the dependent clause if it appears in the main clause: *"We had manufactured it but donated it to somebody else."*

Comment: 1 definitely looks more normal, although 2 might pass as well. There's certainly no requirement to make the second verb here past perfect. Hopefully someone can follow with a more formal grammatical analysis.

Comment: 2. is clearly ungrammatical. You have a choice between the past perfect "had given" or the preterite "gave" as in 1.

Comment: @johnlawler Is either of these ungrammatical?

Comment: I wouldn't say so; each is a grammatical application of Conjunction Reduction on a different grammatical sentence. (1) reduces _**We** had manufactured it but **we** gave it to someone else_ (duplicate reduced part boldface), while (2) reduces _**We had** manufactured it but **we had** given it to someone else_. Conjunction Reduction isn't only for pronouns.